# Free Joomla Extensions to submit my k2 items on Facebook and Tumblr?

Tags: joomla-2.5

My priority is to find something (free) to submit my K2 items on Tumblr if possible.

I know there is obSocialSubmit from Foobla but it's a Paid extension.
If there are no free extensions to do this, can you list me all the paid extensions that do this so I can decide which one to buy?
Maybe writing PROs and CONs for every extension.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if this kind of questions should be allowed. But FYI http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=k2+tumblr. AutoTweet could be an idea.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook auto-publishing, you can find several Free extensions in JED: extensions.joomla.org/category/social-web/social-share

However, integrating K2 or Tumblr as a channel, it will most likely require a paid extension.

JED's Reviews are a good source of information to know each extension.